# How to persist firebase Authentication from firebase REST API

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Signing in into my firebase app via REST https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth only returns tokens which expire after 1 hour (3600 seconds, according to the REST response). I don't see any way to change this.

Using firebase JS SDK, the authentication persists "forever", which is what I would like to achieve. However I do not want to include the JS SDK in my app, if there is a way around it (mostly because of its size (~700kb)).

Is there a way to obtain a persistent login from the official firebase REST api?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Using firebase JS SDK, the authentication persists "forever"

This is because the JS SDK **automatically** takes in charge the action of getting a new user's Firebase ID token when the current one expires, by using the refresh token. See the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/users?authuser=0#the_user_lifecycle).

So you need to implement this mechanism yourself when you work with the Firebase Auth REST API, by using the [endpoint that allows exchanging a refresh token for an ID token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-refresh-token).

For that you should use the refresh token you received the last time you logged in, e.g. by using the [endpoint that signs in a user with email/password](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-sign-in-email-password), or the last time you refreshed the ID token (see below).

You'll get a response which contains the new Firebase ID token and refresh token. Next time this new ID token expires, use again the refresh token, and so forth...

Comment: Wow, now that you wrote it this became obvious, but just by looking at the firebase (REST) doc I didn't have no idea about the token lifecycles...

Comment: cool answer which can provide similar idea for various sdk-s in different languages! thanks [:

Comment: This is super helpful, thank you.  But once I have an updated ID token... What do I do with it? Ideally I'd be able to log the user in using just that token, but I'm not sure how it works, and can't find documentation on it.

Comment: You just need to use the new (refreshed) token with the subsequent calls to the REST API endpoints (e.g. calling the Firestore REST API). See the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api#authenticating_with_an_access_token)